# Convert UTC DateTime to specific time zone xamarin forms pcl

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on a project in which i am getting UTC DateTime in service response.
I am trying to convert UTC DateTime to Datetime in specific time zone. i have tried **System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId** but it is unavailable in xamarin forms pcl.

Is there any solution or workaround to handle this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: So do you already *have* the `TimeZoneInfo` that you want to convert into? More details would be helpful.

Comment: I am getting UTC DateTime after parsing the json from service. I am trying to change timezone by TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId method but it is missing. There is TimeZoneInfo.Convert method is present.

Comment: But what time zone are you trying to use?

Comment: US & Canada, Alaska, Gaza and many more.

Comment: So what identifiers do you have for those? If they're Windows time zone IDs, they won't work on a non-Windows platform. If they're IANA time zone IDs (such as "Europe/London") then you *may* be able to get them to work using `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById`, but you might also want to use my Noda Time project.

Comment: I will Sir, Thanks

Comment: This might be helpful for you/anyone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59281255/4841439

Comment: This question has answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59281255/4841439

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `ToLocalDateTime()` this way:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
var test = date.ToLocalDateTime();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will use the Local timezone, not a selected TimeZone

Comment: Isn't it `ToLocalTime()`?

Answer (score 2):

Try below code:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

Comment: I think it's important to read the question before answering

Comment: @BriceFriha I believe this answer is actually correct. Obviously you would replace `TimeZoneInfo.Local` with whatever timezone you would like to have. Maybe the answer could have explaned that but still using `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` is the correct solution. It works for me at least

Comment: @Ivo, you're right; I don't think I was being fair in this comment now that I think about it. I'm glad this answer helped you!