# Xamarin Form: How do i change from current device time to different country time

Tags: datetime, xamarin, timezone, currentculture

I am not too familiar with date time. I am currently wonder how can I convert the existing time of the device to a different countries' date/time.

E.g. App.CurrentDate <- which display the  device setting date/time. I want it to be in different country's time when choosing different site where the site can be any countries

Is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Android and iOS use IANA timezone names. They look like this “America/New_York” and you can find a list of them at the List of [tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

```
TimeZoneInfo estZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/New_York");
DateTime estTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, estZone);
```

**References**:

1 http://www.xamarinhelp.com/time-zones-xamarin-forms/

2 https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/scheduler/timezone

Answer (score -2):

Grab the current date and time in UTC format first

```
var utcTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Then convert it to whichever timezone you need

```
TimeZoneInfo zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
DateTime zoneTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, zone);
```

[Here is how to get a list of all the time zones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908343/list-of-timezone-ids-for-use-with-findtimezonebyid-in-c)

[More details about UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)

It's also possible to identify the timezone based on co-ordinates - [this answer shows how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639571/get-local-time-based-on-coordinates)

Comment: I have tested but it give me this error Exception of type 'System.TimeZoneNotFoundException' was thrown.

Comment: When I put NZ instead of New Zealand Standard Time, it will work on both iOS and Android. The Central Standard Time will lead me to exception. I wonder will be device specific

Comment: Other problem : What if the TimeZone not support? Are there any other alternatives that can guarantee to get the time.

Comment: Always returns TimeZoneNotFoundException.